# How to run eclipse from inside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to create a very simple eclipse project (plugin/feature/product/whatever) that when executed, creates a new instance of eclipse, just as the instance that is currently installed in my system.

This should be a simple task to accomplish, but I have searched the internet and didn't find any working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a plugin
2. Right click on the plugin in the project explorer
3. Select 'Run As Eclipse Application' (or something like that)

And a new Eclipse instance is started running/including your plugin.